# Add Unique values from a specific range(column) into a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, unique, userform

I am trying to add values from a specific range(column) into a listbox. However, the range has blank  cells and duplicates that I am trying to get rid of. The following code works (no error msg) and does populate the listbox, but it does not get rid of the duplicates.

Can someone help?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rang, rang1 As Range
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim list(), ListUniq() As Variant
Dim iRw As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Paramed Verification Grid")
    Set rang = ws.Range("E3").CurrentRegion
    lstrow = rang.Rows.Count + 1
    Set rang1 = Range("E3:E" & lstrow)
    'list = ws.Range("E3:E" & lstrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Resize Array prior to loading data
    ReDim list(WorksheetFunction.CountA(rang1))
    'Loop through each cell in Range and store value in Array
    x = 0
    For Each cell In rang1
        If cell <> "" Then
            list(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Unique(list)

    ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Sort(ListUniq)
    ProviderListBx.list = ListUniq

End Sub
```

Comment: You assign cell values to `list(x)`, `WorksheetFunction.Unique` expects a range as input. Consider loading the values in a dictionary instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289410/vba-dictionary-remove-duplicate)

Comment: Unique's base setting is to use a vertical array.  You need to tell it that the array is horizontal.  `ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Unique(list,True)`  Same with Sort: `ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Sort(ListUniq,1,1,True)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Unique will use an array just fine.  But I do agree that a Dictionary would probably be a quicker and better solution, albeit more code.